# First 10 digits of $\pi$ without rounding

Tags: numerics

I need to have $\pi$ with an accuracy of $10$ digits. My first guess would be

```
N[Pi, 10]
```

However, this rounds to the last digit instead of just chopping of any additional digits and hence the last digit is $4$ (and not $3$, as it actually is).

I could do

```
N[FromDigits[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10]], 10]
```

but I am pretty sure that there are nicer solutions.

Comment: Maybe `IntegerPart[Pi 10^9]/10.^9`:)

Comment: Floor[N[Pi, 11], 0.000000001]. Frankly, this looks like a non-problem.

Comment: If you just want to print it..`StringTake[ToString[N[Pi, 11]], 11]`

Comment: `3.141592653` :-)

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions. Actually, Pi is just an example for a number. So what I want is to get the first n digits of a number a, without rounding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only need 10 digits of precision there's a ComputerArithmetic package that allows you to specify your rounding method under limited conditions.

```
Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"]
SetArithmetic[10, RoundingRule->Truncation]
```

This will set up our arithmetic system, but in order to use it, we'll need to use `ComputerNumber[]`

```
N[ComputerNumber[Pi],10]
```

yields an output of 3.141592653

```
N[ComputerNumber[EulerGamma],10]
```

yields an output of 0.5772156649. But keep in mind this is 10 *total* digits of precision so if we do this:

```
N[ComputerNumber[100*EulerGamma],10]
```

we'll get 57.72156649 and not 57.7215664901

If you require more flexible precision you'll want to do what Sjoerd C. de Vries recommended. I've wrapped everything in a `SetPrecision[]` for clarity because without it Mathematica will hide the output of everything but the first 6 significant digits:

```
NTrunc[number_, precision_Integer] := 
 SetPrecision[
  Floor[
   N[number, precision + 1], 
   10^-(precision - 1)], 
  precision]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a round-about method, after the [BBP algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBPFormula.html) (discovered by a computer! * ) :-

```
Round[NSum[
   (4/(8 n + 1) - 2/(8 n + 4) - 1/(8 n + 5) - 1/(8 n + 6))/16^n,
   {n, 0, 5}], 10.^-9] // InputForm
```

> 3.141592653

`*` "The formula itself was found by a computer program, and almost certainly constitutes the first instance of a computer program finding a significant new formula for pi." - [D.H.Bailey](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/bbp-alg.pdf)

Comment: hmm.. i think this only works because the approximation happens to round the right way.  Were there a base 10 anaolg of the bpp formula then you'd have something.

Comment: @george2079 - yes, the approximate rounding was convenient ;-)

Comment: I hope it was obvious that I only summed to the 5th term rather than infinity, as the proper formula has it.

Comment: interesting! but as I just commented above, I am not only interested in Pi but also other numbers.

Comment: @traindriver - then I would have said your `RealDigits` method was best, but hifigi's `ComputerNumber` is even better, and it works with negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I liked  george2079 solution in the comments above, so here is a Manipulate using it, just for fun (I have slow coffee maker :)

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 n,
 Grid[{
   {N[Pi, 50], SpanFromLeft},
   {Dynamic[StringTake[ToString[N[Pi, n]], n]], SpanFromLeft},
   {Control[{{n, 10, "N?"}, 2, 50, 1, ImageSize -> Medium}], 
    Dynamic[n]}
   }, Alignment -> Left],
 TrackedSymbols :> {n},
 ImageMargins -> 0,
 FrameMargins -> 0,
 ContentSize -> {0},
 AppearanceElements -> "ManipulateMenu",
 Paneled -> False
 ]
```

Comment: nice one! but as stated above, Pi just served as an example for any number...